# Javascript not loading after the document ready

Tags: functions, javascript

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'loadingscripts' ) ) {
function loadingscripts() {
        // Register the script like this for a theme:
        wp_register_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );

        /* Load the stylesheets. */
        // wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome', THEMEROOT . '/inc/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'layout', THEMEROOT . '/css/layout.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', THEMEROOT . '/css/style.css' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','loadingscripts');
```

I think the Javascript is loading before the DOM because in its pure HTML version I was loading the javascript in the footer, but in the WordPress conversion, it doesn't work. What is the fix?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is the file (custom,js) not correctly loaded or is the code in it not executed as you expect? (for the latter, we obviously need at least parts of the code). Are you using `jQuery` and not `$` (which does not work by default in WP)?

Comment: js is loaded, but I think the JS loads earlier than DOM so menus are not working which are dependent on custom.js. Did u get it?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ /* your code here */ });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript runs as soon as it's loaded, you need to wait for the DOM ready event, and you do that in JS, not in WP:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    /* your code here */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my custom scripts to the bottom of my footer by editing the add_action

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','loadingscripts', 9999);`

The 3rd parameter is the priority that your function loads in. giving it a 9999 value will push it to the bottom.  if you know the code works on its own my best guess would be that its a plugin's script file that is not playing nice with your script.